# Use rabbitmq to rent an order between several docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, rabbitmq, queue

I have a few container dockers installed on each container of a laravel.
Each Laravel is supposed to execute the command to execute the queue`php artisan queue:work`.
I want to do this with another container on which RabbitMQ is installed.
Can I do the following commands on RabbitMQ?

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run these commands on each of laravel containers to start work.
You can run this command at docker startup using [entrypoint](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21)

```
docker run -it laravel1 php artisan queue:work
```